# HTML prev function on td is returning null or empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, html-table

In a `<table>`with check box in the Last column, on selection of whcih I want to sum the values of previous two `<td>`.
The `js` function should sum the values of the columns for which the `CheckBox` is `ticked`. But I am stuck at locating the previous `<td>` itself. The Snippet is as follows.

```js
function doSumAeFunction(){
          var prevCell = $(this).closest('tr').prev('td').text();
           console.log(prevCell);
           alert(prevCell);
       }
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid purple;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table style="table table-bordered text-center" style="width:auto">
  <thead>
    <th>Sl No</th>
    <th>English</th>
    <th>Geography</th>
    <th>Maths</th>
    <th>Science 2</th>
    <th align="center">Select</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="checked" onclick="doSumAeFunction()"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>5</td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" value="checked" onclick="doSumAeFunction()"  />
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />

<div>
  <div>Sum of Marks</div>
  <div id="sum_of_maths">Sum of Maths is: </div>
  <div id="sum_of_science">Sum of Science is: </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's `prev()` not `prev` and `$('checkbox')` won't select anything since there is no checkbox element. It's an input

Comment: Yes sir, amended that error in the snippet  and now calling a function but still not working.

Comment: Well it's not working in your above example because you didn't include jQuery and `$(this)` now has no meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value in the cell before the checkbox use `$(this).parent().prev('td').text()`:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var prevCell = $(this).parent().prev('td').text();
  console.log(prevCell);
})
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid purple;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table style="table table-bordered text-center" style="width:auto">
  <thead>
    <th>Sl No</th>
    <th>English</th>
    <th>Geography</th>
    <th>Maths</th>
    <th>Science 2</th>
    <th align="center">Select</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="checked" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="checked" />
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />

<div>
  <div>Sum of Marks</div>
  <div id="sum_of_maths">Sum of Maths is: </div>
  <div id="sum_of_science">Sum of Science is: </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can `$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {}` be written inside a `function`? Something like `function doSumAeFunction(){}` being triggered with `onclick()` placed in the `<td>` definition.

Comment: Of course, but why?

Comment: `$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {} ` isn't getting triggered...I dunno why.

Comment: You can see it works in my answer. Did you include jQuery? What errs are you getting in the console?

Comment: Yes JSFiddle works but on browser control, there is no output. Tried putting an `alert()' which isn't shownig when `checkbox` is clicked.

Comment: Ok got it. I need to put it in `$( document ).ready()`.. Working now. Thank you